# What is the preferred syntax for nesting a reagent hiccup element that is returned from a function?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, hiccup

Given a function to return an element:

```
(defn title []
  [:h1 "Hello World"])
```

What is the preferred way of nesting this inside another component?

I've seen it done in a tutorial by wrapping the function call in a vector:

```
[:div {:class "app"}
  [title]]
```

but this seemed a little weird to me as the return value of `title` is a vector itself and so would expand to `[[:h1 "Hello World"]]`. What happens to the outer vector?

It also works to just evaluate the function inline:

```
[:div {:class "app"}
  (title)]
```

but I'm not sure if this is a good idea given the mix of parens and square brackets it could be hard to read.

Any opinions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more specific to reagent than to hiccup(ish html-generators) --
it may or may not work with different frameworks or hiccup on the
server-side.

Reagent takes a function in place of a "tag" and treats it as a react
component.  Note that `[title]` is not *calling* the function.  It's a
vector, that holds the reference to the function.

So the difference here is, whether you want `title` being treated like
a component (with all that comes with it (when using `[title]`)) or if
you just call `(title)` there and it will place the result right there in the vector.

There is a whole [tutorial page](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/2e1931e584d47423f9b98b7e20697786833d93be/doc/UsingSquareBracketsInsteadOfParens.md) dedicated to that:

> So, which variation of greet-family (square vs round) should I choose,
> and why?
>
> The answer to "which?" is easy: you almost certainly want the square
> version. "why?" takes more explanation ...
>
> First off, let's acknowledge that both variations will ultimately
> produce the same DOM, so in that respect they are the same.
>
> Despite this identical outcome, they differ in one significant way:
>
> 1. the square version will create each greet child as a distinct React
>    component, each with its own React lifecycle, allowing them to
>    re-render independently of siblings.
> 2. The round version causes the greet hiccup for all children to be
>    incorporated into the hiccup returned by the parent, forming one
>    large data structure, parent and children all in together. So, each
>    time the parent re-renders, all the greet children are effectively
>    re-rendered too. React must then work out what, in this tree, has
>    changed.
>
> As a result, the square version will be more efficient at "re-render
> time". Only the DOM which needs to be re-rendered will be done. At our
> toy scale in this tutorial it hardly matters but, if greet was a more
> substantial child component, this gain in efficiency could be
> significant.

Comment: You might also add a link to the Reagent documentation that covers this topic and goes into more detail (https://cljdoc.org/d/reagent/reagent/1.0.0/doc/tutorials/using-square-brackets-instead-of-parentheses-)